# NotificationManager.notify locks the phone and Emulator

Tags: android, android-notifications

**PROBLEM:**

The phone/emulator locks up on repeated Notification updates. The only way to get the emulator back responsive after it gets locked is by pressing Home => Menu => Lock => Home => Menu Button in that given order.

**CODE:**

Notification pushing code:

```
        // Set up notifcation views
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); // Get notification manager
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.service_notification);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.current_error_text, View.GONE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.error_text, View.GONE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.info_error_text, View.GONE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.info_text, View.GONE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.next_check_in_text, View.VISIBLE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.current_profile_text, View.VISIBLE);
        contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.profile_name_text, View.VISIBLE);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.next_check_in_text, mainText);
        // Set profile text now
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.profile_name_text, miniText);
        // Set up a new notification
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.service_logo_small, "Service is running", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.contentView = contentView; // Set content view
        // Create and plug in the PendingIntent
        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, EntryPointActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifIntent, 0); // Set up the Pending Intent
        notif.contentIntent = pIntent;
        // Now set up notification flags
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
        if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateLights", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateVibrate", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateSound", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        notificationManager.notify(R.string.app_name, notif);
```

All objects exist and the project compiles perfectly. I encounter NO NullPointerExceptions!

Code calling the notification creating function:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run() {
    if(( nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis() ) > 0) {
        long milliseconds = (nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis());
        int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
        int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
        String toShow = "Next Check In: " + minutes + " minute" + ((minutes != 1) ? "s" : "") + " " + seconds + " second" + ((seconds != 1) ? "s" : "");
        pushNotification(STATE_LOADEDSUCCESSFULLY, currentProfile.getProfileName(), toShow);
    } else {
        currentState = STATE_RELOADING;
        pushNotification(STATE_RELOADING, null, "Refreshing..");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
}, 1, 999);
```

Again, all objects exist!
The notification **IS UPDATED** in the above process but it locks up **BOTH THE EMULATOR AND PHONE** as mentioned above!

**AIM:**

To update notification in the Status Bar to basically show a countdown till the next refresh.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to run this code via a **SERVICE** and I've tried on emulators running Android 2.2, 2.3.3, 4.1 and all of them give me the same problem!

Comment: you can try increasing the period of the timer to check if repetitive push of notifications is causing the issue or not. I had a similar scenario, where i had mistakenly set the period to 300ms , which caused the app to freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured what the problem is.

You may be interested in this link too: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13941#c12

So, according to the above link, I stopped create a new **Notification** object everytime the notification pushing function is called. Now, I create the object once and keep reusing it! This has stopped the emulator lock ups!

Following is the modification to the **Notification pushing code**:

```
    // Set up notifcation views
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.service_notification);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.current_error_text, View.GONE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.error_text, View.GONE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.info_error_text, View.GONE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.info_text, View.GONE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.next_check_in_text, View.VISIBLE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.current_profile_text, View.VISIBLE);
    contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.profile_name_text, View.VISIBLE);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.next_check_in_text, mainText);
    // Set profile text now
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.profile_name_text, miniText);
    // Set up a new notification
    notif.contentView = contentView; // Set content view
    // Create and plug in the PendingIntent
    Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, EntryPointActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifIntent, 0); // Set up the Pending Intent
    notif.contentIntent = pIntent;
    // Now set up notification flags
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
    if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateLights", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateVibrate", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    if(sp.getBoolean("UpdateSound", true)) notif.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notificationManager.notify(R.string.app_name, notif);
```

You'd probably be seeing that the **NotificationManager** and **Notification** are no longer being created in the notification pushing code.

Following are the changes I made to the timer:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); // Get notification manager
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.service_logo_small, "Service is running", System.currentTimeMillis());
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run() {
    if(( nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis() ) > 0) {
        long milliseconds = (nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis());
        int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
        int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
        String toShow = "Next Check In: " + minutes + " minute" + ((minutes != 1) ? "s" : "") + " " + seconds + " second" + ((seconds != 1) ? "s" : "");
        pushNotification(STATE_LOADEDSUCCESSFULLY, currentProfile.getProfileName(), toShow);
    } else {
        currentState = STATE_RELOADING;
        pushNotification(STATE_RELOADING, null, "Refreshing..");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
}, 1, 999);
```

As you may be seeing, I reuse the object **notificationManager** and **notif** in the timer and thus the CPU is not burdened to re-create the Notification object every time the Timer is being executed.

So, with the above code changes my code now works perfectly!

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code for displaying and updating notifications works just fine.

It seems to me that the only cause for this could be that many timers are being constructed simultaneously. Since the initial delay is 1 millisecond, you may be locking up the system with hundreds of notification updates if `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` is being called through some unintended loop. I would suggest placing a breakpoint on that line and figuring out why that's happening.

I have two additional suggestions:

1. Bear in mind that the `Notification` constructor is now deprecated, and you should probably consider using a notification builder such as Jake Wharton's [NotificationCompat2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2).
2. It's recommended to use [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of `Timer`.

Comment: I've tried the second suggestion but I still face the SAME problem. Code is at: http://pastebin.com/dfysMRzb. And about the first suggestion, I'm still using the Gingerbread APIs, so I guess it is not yet depreciated in those APIs!

Comment: When is `stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate()` being called? It should only start once. Also make sure to shut it down when you're done with it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dfysMRzb: This is the exact piece of code chunk that is running there in the program. It is being called once and you can look at the shutdown and scheduleAtFixedRate() code too!

Comment: `isShutdown` will always be `false` in your snippet. I can't actually see where `scheduleAtFixedRate()` is being executed, and sincerely believe that that is the cause of your problems.

Comment: The last line: stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(updaterRunnable, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Yes, I see that in your snippet. My question is *when* is that line executed?

Comment: Thanks for posting your resolution. I coincidentally encountered a related issue on Jelly Bean causing an ongoing notification to animate out and back in because I was recreating it instead of updating the existing instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with @Paul Lammertsma in assumption that your code produces a great load. However, executing timer task every 999 ms won't be a problem, I guess the problem is in your "Notification pushing code". Anyway, you should use [method profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to determine what is the bottleneck.

P.S. I think, there is an small bug in your code here:

```
if (( nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis() ) > 0) {
    long milliseconds = (nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis());
    // milliseconds may still be negative here
    ...
```

You probably wanted this:

```
long milliseconds = nextUpdateIn - System.currentTimeMillis();
if (milliseconds > 0) {
    ...
```

P.P.S. Why do you use `Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` flag?

Comment: If `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` is being executed in a loop, endless new timers will be creating notifications with the initial 1ms delay, not subsequent 999ms delay. Otherwise, I agree with your sentiment.